# Add value to known mean and Standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a distribution that will continuously have numbers added to it as they are measured.
I want to keep only knowledge of the mean, the standard deviation, and the number of values so far in the distribution.
How would I go about adding a new value to the distribution and correctly recalculating the standard deviation? (I can do the mean).
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the mean when we have $N$ values as $\bar x_N$. Then:
$$
\bar x_{N+1}=\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}x_i=\frac{N}{N+1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}x_i+\frac{1}{N+1}x_{N+1}=
$$
$$
=\frac{N}{N+1}\bar x_N+\frac{1}{N+1}x_{N+1}
$$
You already had it, but I didn't remember it and it is necessary for the next one. Notating the standard deviation when we have $N$ values as $\sigma_N$:
$$
\sigma^2_{N+1}=\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}(x_i-\bar x_{N+1})^2=\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{i=1}^{N+1}(x_i^2-\bar x_{N+1}^2)
$$

$$
=\frac{N}{N+1}\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(x_i^2-\bar x_{N}^2)+\frac{1}{N+1}\sum_{i=1}^{N}(\bar x_{N}^2-\bar x_{N+1}^2)+\frac{1}{N+1}(x^2_{N+1}-\bar x^2_{N+1})
$$
$$
=\frac{N}{N+1}\sigma^2_N+\frac{N}{N+1}(\bar x_{N}^2-\bar x_{N+1}^2)+\frac{1}{N+1}(x^2_{N+1}-\bar x^2_{N+1})
$$
I think that it should be enought.